# Rspec and rails: Problems while testing libraries in the lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, specifications

I have some classes in the lib directory, and I want to test it. My class which I want to test looks like:

```
class StatAggregation
  class << self
    def skills_rate(user_id)
      user_id = User.find_by_id(user_id)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

I created spec:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../spec_helper')

describe StatAggregation do
  fixtures [
    :users
  ]

  describe 'skills_rate method' do
    it 'should work' do
      @user_id = 1
      @user = mock_model(User)
      User.should_receive(:find_by_id).with(@user_id).and_return(@user)    
      ...
      StatAggregation.skills_rate(@user_id)
    end
  end
end
```

It works ok, but it doesn't show where appeared error:

```
1)
ArgumentError in 'PxStatAggregation skills_rate method should work'
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
script/spec:10:

Finished in 0.326331 seconds
```

How to get number of line where appeared error "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add -b or --backtrace to spec command-line or to your spec.opts file.